# Tell Google Adsense not to use special page content for ad generating

Tags: adsense, ads

I have terms and data policy in the footer of my website which will show up inside a lightbox popup. The content is inside a div with CSS -> display: none
This is needed that the lightbox is working.

How can I tell Google Adsense not to use the terms and data policy content for generating ads showing up on the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Inclose the content for the Google Adsense Crawler between this tags.

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start -->
**here should be your content**
<!-- google_ad_section_end -->
```

Comment: Since recently section targeting is obsolete and it is (probably) ignored by Mediapartners-Google https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/23168?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct syntax is:

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->
*** here is the ignored content
<!-- google_ad_section_end -->
```